# How to make a Fabric EventStream customapp EventHub not strip the braces from the payload

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I'm running into problems in downstream processing due to the Fabric EventStream source customapp EventHub stripping the braces from the payload. If I use an Azure EventHub as the source, this is not a problem. Does anyone know how to make the Fabric EventStream customapp EventHub not strip the braces from the payload?

Example:

| Azure EventHub | customapp EventHub |
| --- | --- |
| [{...}] | {...} |